# Join three tables that do not all share foreign keys

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have three tables: `event`, `location` and `itinerary`. `Event` and `itinerary` have a `foreign key` constraint. `Location` and `itinerary` have a `foreign key` constraint. `Itinerary` has a `foreign key` constraint on both `location` and `event`.

I would like to select an `event` and join the `itinerary` and `location` to the query. However, I am trying to figure out the best way to do this. I could just select from the itinerary table, however, an event can have multiple itinerary entries and i only need to grab the earliest itinerary. This is the code I have so far, it is failing with:

> INVALID SYNTAX on line 11

```
SELECT e.id,
    (SELECT i.start_time FROM "itinerary" i WHERE e.id = i.event_id ORDER BY start_time LIMIT 1),
    (SELECT i.end_time FROM "itinerary" i WHERE e.id = i.event_id ORDER BY end_time LIMIT 1),
    e.event_name, e.description, e.is_plan, e.timestamp, e.organizer_id, e.event_type_id, et.value,
    e.curated, l.city, l.state_province, l.country, l.geolocation
    AS event_type_value, ep.privacy
    AS event_privacy
    FROM "event" e
    INNER JOIN event_type et ON e.event_type_id = et.id
    INNER JOIN event_privacy ep ON e.event_privacy_id = ep.id
    INNER JOIN location l WHERE i.location_id = l.id
    WHERE  e.premium=True AND l.city = 'Madrid';
```

I am pretty sure it is because I am trying to create a relationship between two unrelated tables. So my question is what should I do? Should I use a `CROSS JOIN`, `SUB QUERY` or select from Itinerary and join the other related tables? If I went with the last option how could i select the itinerary that has the earliest start date since one event can have multiple itineraries?

Answer (score 0):

try change your line 11 to

```
INNER JOIN location l ON i.location_id = l.id
```

instead of

```
INNER JOIN location l WHERE i.location_id = l.id
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. Thanks for trying though...